# MVC 5 Authorize Attribute Stored Procedure not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I'm trying to add Role Based Authorization to our webpage but having this usual error;

```
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
```

I found that usual solution is to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` but I'm told not to do it. Main reason being concerns about the DB state as it would add lots of tables and Stored Procedures to it.

I'm trying to find some other approach to handle this matter but so far nothing I found worked.

I checked our connection string, looks OK. I noticed it didn't have integratedsecurity part, added it. App stopped working.

Tried adding `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>` to App.Setting, didn't work either.

What else I can try?

Comment: create your own user model and extend authorization, can start from here http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/custom-authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom authorization attribute by extending the authorize attribute. For more details and step by step tutorial you may refer [Custom Roles Based Access Control (RBAC) in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1079552/custom-roles-based-access-control-rbac-in-asp-ne)